# How to gracefully shutdown Mariadb?

Tags: mariadb

I have to shutdown a mariaDB machine which is a part of galera cluster, which have only read access for secondaries. How can i shutdown mariaDb gracefully so that all the connections read successfully completes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a load-balancer or other proxy in front of the nodes?  If so, turn that off, then wait for connections to terminate.

Do you have sufficient error checking in your clients?  If so, simply "pull the plug".  The clients will catch the error, and recover.